# How to get "note link" with Evernote Python SDK

Tags: python, evernote

I am building a Python script that will fetch all the notes from a particular notebook and generates a Markdown file with links for all notes of that notebook.

My question is, using the Python SDK is there any way to get the "note link"? I cant find it in the documentation.

Thank you.

Comment: What kind of note link are you talking about? There are two types:

- a "public link" which gives anyone access to the note via the link

- a "note link" which links to the note, but you need to be logged in as a user who already has access to the note

Comment: The link between notes.